# SQL, PHP Get total count while paging before sqlsrv_fetch_array

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I found a good query that get total count while paging:

```
    DECLARE
        @PageSize INT = 15,
        @PageNum  INT = '.$page_num.';

    WITH TempResult AS(
        SELECT *
        FROM V_Item_Voice
    ), TempCount AS (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS MaxRows FROM TempResult
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM TempResult, TempCount
    ORDER BY TempResult.ItemNum
        OFFSET (@PageNum-1)*@PageSize ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

From that query, I can get one more extra row `MaxRows` that show the total count. The table looks like:

```
---------------------
id | name  | MaxRows
---------------------
1  | demo2 | 95
---------------------
2  | demo2 | 95
---------------------
```

Then to get it in PHP, I do this:

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($connection, $query);
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){}
```

I don't know what is a good way to get the total result (which is `MaxRows`) before doing the while loop. Or I have to get that inside the loop? Can anybody show me. Thank you.

Comment: What is `db_com_fetch_array`? It seems that you are PHP Driver for SQL Server (based on `sqlsrv_query()` call).

Comment: @Zhorov Sorry, it's just `sqlsrv_fetch_array`, my typo

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to generate two separate statements, but execute them with one `sqlsrv_query()` call. In this situation, the first result set will return the row count and the second one will return the actual data.

With PHP Driver for SQL Server you can easily fetch data from different result sets using `sqlsrv_next_result()`. Also, use parameters for the paging. Function `sqlsrv_query()` does both statement preparation and statement execution, and can be used to execute parameterized queries:

Example (based on your code):

```
<?php
// Connection
$servername = "server\instance,port";
$cinfo = array(
    "UID" => 'username',
    "PWD" => 'password',
    "Database" => 'database'
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($servername, $cinfo);
if ($conn === false) {
    die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Statement
$pageSize = 15;
$pageNum = 1;
$query = "
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS MaxRows 
    FROM V_Item_Voice;

    SELECT *
    FROM V_Item_Voice
    ORDER BY ItemNum
        OFFSET (? - 1) * ? ROWS
        FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY;
";
$params = array($pageNum, $pageSize, $pageSize);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params);
if ($stmt === false) {
    echo "Error";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// First result set. Fetch row count
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "Row count: ".$row["MaxRows"]."<br>";
}

// Second resultset. Fetch actual data
if (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt) === false) {
    echo print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}   
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row["name"]."<br>";
}

// End
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that you have at least one PK field:

```
SELECT colID, col1, col2, ... 1 AS RowCount FROM myTable OFFSET ...
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, ... COUNT(*) AS RowCount FROM myTable
```

The record where the ID/PK column is NULL is your total count, the rest is your page.

Or if you want the row count as a separate column, you can do

```
SELECT
  SRC.colID, SRC.col1, SRC.col2, ... , RC.RowCount
FROM
  (
    SELECT colID, col1, col2, ... 1 AS RowCount FROM myTable OFFSET ...
  ) AS SRC
  CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS RowCount FROM myTable
  ) AS RC
```